# Передать char в максос define

Tags: c, строки, char

Я программирую на php но сейчас возникла необходимость поправить кое что в си.
Си очень отличается и у меня возникли некоторые сложности со строками, поэтому прошу помочь советом.

Задача.
Мне нужно вставить переменную в выводимую строку. Строка у автора была определена как

```
#define string "string text"
```

Мне нужно сделать так:

```
#define string "string var text"
```

где var - переменная типа char которая генерируется программой динамически.

Попытка 1
Попробовал разделить на два макроса и потом объединить так:

```
#define str1 "string"
#define str2 "text"

result = strcat(result,str1);
result = strcat(result,var);
result = strcat(result,str2);
```

Но получаю ошибку в виде крякозяблей.

Попытка 2
Попытался передать переменную макросу

```
#define str(var) str1 var str2

const char* var = "wwwww";
result = str(var);
```

Но получил следующую ошибку

```
error: expected ';' before 'var'
```

Что не могу понять.
То это почему когда я передаю строку не как char а как "wwww" так

```
result = str("wwww");
```

то всё работает.

Comment: Строка "before var after" нужна именно как строка, т.к. дальше она не выводится на экран, а используется для передачи в другую функцию.

Answer (score 1):

Препроцессор работает до любого анализа кода. Он просто не понимает, что такое ваше `var`.

```
cost char * var = "insert";
char * result = malloc(/* ставить нужный размер памяти*/) 
// или char result[100] - ну, достаточное количество...

strcpy(result, "before ");
strcat(result, var);
strcat(result, " after");
```

Еще вариант

```
sprintf(result,"before %s after",var);
```

Примерно так. Препроцессор вообще лучше трогать поменьше...

Comment: Ещё можно использовать расширение GNU asprintf

Comment: Помогло, большое спасибо.